# How do you remove Facebook birthday from "My Calendars"?

Tags: sync, calendar, facebook

My calendar is full of facebook friend birthdays! and worse, they are listed under "My Calendar", not Facebook calendar, so I can't hide them by unchecking Facebook in Calendar, Settings > Calendars. Even thouh they are listed under My Calendar, they still have facebook logos on the entry and a sync logo. I tried by turning off the sync option, but they are still there. How can I remove them from my calendars, and add them to the "facebook" calendar?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Facebook event I accepted by mistake, can't get rid of it off my calendar either. Even although I've removed it in Facebook.

Comment: birthday is worse because it makes your calendar really full, lol.

Comment: How did they get there to begin with?  Via the official Facebook app or something else?

Comment: I think it must have gotten there from built-in account sync. I can remove my facebook account and check whether they still remain, but I'm a bit reluctant to do this because 1) it will mess with my contacts and 2) I'm not sure whether the birthday will really be removed when I do that.

Comment: i have all my FB birthdays on my Google calendar TWICE.  I have a Sprint Samsung Epic.  Any thoughts?  I don't want any FB birthdays on my Google Calendar at all.

Answer (score 4):

This was reported in the Android Central forum [here](http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g/15384-want-remove-facebook-birthdays-phone-calendar.html) with a link to LifeHacker. It sounds like it will allow you to sync your Facbook calendar without the birthdays because you're exporting the events directly from Facebook. First, you may want to undo the sync that you have going on now. Hope it helps.

Quoting the post from Android Central:

> just go to your google
>   calendar thats linked with your google
>   account on your phone and then follow
>   this article.
>
> [Add Your Facebook Events to Google
>   Calendar](http://lifehacker.com/5391880/add-your-facebook-events-to-google-calendar)
>
> 1. In Facebook, go to your EVENTS page.
> 2. At the top of that page click EXPORT EVENTS
> 3. You'll get a pop up window with a URL, copy it.
> 4. In Google Cal, on the bottom left you'll see ‘Other Calendars' and below
>      that a link to ADD. Click ADD
> 5. One of the new options you'll be presented with is ADD BY URL, select
>      that
> 6. Paste the URL from Facebook where it asks for it.
>
> and thats it! when your phone calendar
>   syncs with your google calendar, all
>   your facebook events will show up too
>   and no birthdays.

Comment: the problem is that the birthdays show up as entries from "My Calendar", not as a Facebook event (they still have facebook logos on the entry and a sync logo though). I unchecked Facebook from calendar sync setting but still the birthday show up in the calendar.

Comment: It may be because the birthday's are syncing through the Contact Sync, then syncing from your contacts to your calendar.

Comment: @matt: how to cancel that?

Comment: I awarded the bounty because it's about to expire and I dont want to just lose 50 rep to the air :D but still the issue is not solved :(

Comment: @Louis I wanted to earn that bounty so I added Facebook to accounts that sync, then added FB to the calendar. Birthdays only show up when I have a the FB calendar added. Like @Matt suggests, it could be something other than FB that's causing this. Trying playing around with which accounts are synced. Go to Settings > Accounts & Sync (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

Go into **Accounts and sync** in Settings and remove Facebook HTC Sense and your calendar will be back to normal. Stupid thing had my calendar full of birthdays from my Facebook that I don't really care about....

Answer (score 1):

There is a downward-pointing arrow on the top right of of the calendar. Hit this, and a list of all your calendars drops down. Untick the ones whose events you don't want synched to your phone's calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I simply stopped syncing the Sense Facebook app to fix this.  However, all the contacts I connected with Facebook are gone as well which is the down side.